# Django - how to get all models bound to post_save receivers?

Tags: python, django, debugging, django-signals

I'm working on a script which finds all `Django` `pre_save` and `post_save` signals and comments overwritten `save` methods so programmer is aware of all signals affecting the workflow.

**For Example**

There are two receivers:

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=MyModel)
def sig_mymodel_pre_save(instance, sender, **kwargs):
   ...

@receiver(post_save, sender=MyModel)
def sig_mymodel_post_save(instance, sender, created, **kwargs):
   ...
```

And model **MyModel**:

```
class MyModel(..):
    ...

    def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
        ...
        super().save(...)
        ....
```

I want the script to modify **MyModel** code to look like this:

```
class MyModel(..):
    ...

    def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
        ...
        # SIGNAL pre_save | myapp.models.sig_mymodel_pre_save
        super().save(...)
        # SIGNAL post_save | myapp.models.sig_mymodel_post_save
        ....
```

So the first thing I'm going to do is to list all `receivers` of `post_save` and `pre_save` signals:

```
def get_signals() -> {}:
    result = {}
    for signal in [pre_save, post_save]:
        result[signal] = signal.receivers
    return result

def comment_signals_to_save_methods():

    for signal, receivers in get_receivers():
        for receiver in receivers:
             models = ???
```

And here is the problem - I can't get `models` for the `receiver`. There is no such method or attribute.

Do you know how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

`signal.receivers` is of the form `((receiver_id, sender_id), receiver_ref)`,
i.e. `((id(sig_mymodel_post_save), id(MyModel)), weakref.ref(sig_mymodel_post_save))`.

You can build a lookup:

```py
from django.apps import apps
sender_id_to_model = {id(model): model for model in apps.get_models()}
```

And then:

```py
def comment_signals_to_save_methods():
    for signal, receivers in get_receivers():
        for receiver in receivers:
            (_, sender_id), receiver_ref = receiver
            model = sender_id_to_model[sender_id]
            receiver_name = receiver_ref().__name__
            ...
```

Comment: Here, what is the output of `get_receivers()`?

Comment: `get_receivers = get_signals` in the question.

Answer (score 0):

#### Direct Response

A small disclaimer to start: I'm currently pinned in 1.11, but I'm linking to 4.2 docs & github code references.

I don't think even the [latest version's docs (4.2)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/signals/) mention this, at least on the page I'm familiar with, so this might not be formally supported?

A signal variable does have a `.receivers` variable that might provide some of what you're asking for here?
However, the `Signal.send()` method seems to leverage `self.receivers` and `self.sender_receivers_cache.get(sender)` [for a short-circuit check](https://github.com/django/django/blob/674c23999cb6982a9d447fedec4d72e135201fee/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py#L181-L185), but uses a `self._live_receivers(sender)` [call to actually iterate through & call receivers](https://github.com/django/django/blob/674c23999cb6982a9d447fedec4d72e135201fee/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py#L187-L202), I'm assuming the name is meant to be intuitive there.

I don't have any insights between the three, and the receiver readouts aren't too friendly while debugging at least for django 1.11, so this still might not get you the method names you're after.

And I'd be inclined to call this a hack at best, anyways.

---

#### Alternate Suggestion:

Could I suggest regex or string matching on `<signal>.connect()` and the `@receiver()` wrapper instead? It would take some file parsing of the whole project, but if you're still working on finding the receiver method names, it might be a simpler path for reaching your auto-commenting goal.